# Drawing software for distributing colors randomly to colored areas according to designed color sets with given probability distributions

Tags: drawing, statistics, plug-in, color

I was wondering whether there are any coloring software for computers that allow you to:

- divide part of the drawing area into sections
- divide colors into sets
- assign probability distributions for each color set
- select sets of areas in the drawing area
- for each selected set in the drawing area, assign a set of colors constructed with the given probability distribution, and, color all selected areas in the drawing area, randomly, with randomization provided by the given probability distribution. This is done by clicking on an area element in the drawing area, selecting the desired color set with the desired probability distribution, and clicking on "assign".
- In addition to each color, one could designate a given texture (like can be done in OpenGL with textures), to each color, to give it random shading (by assigning a texture to each color set).

I am thinking that this could be done in Illustrator or Inkscape, perhaps using a plugin.

Can this be done?

Has anyone coded such a plugin (with respective user interface elements)?

Anyone know?

As an application of this plugin, one could color a set of fields, a set of leaves from a plant or hedge plant, or a set of hair bands.

Thanks.